# Set File Size Limit Message

Tags: php, blob

I wonder whether someone could help me please.

I have to admit I'm relatively new to writing PHP so please bear with me.

Through articles I've read on the internet and some first class tutition from one @Marcio on this site, I've put together a script that allows users to save Image Files to a mySQL database.

I've now gone a little further by restricting the size of the file that can be uploaded, but I I'd like to add a warning message that tells why the file cannot be uploaded i.e. because it's size is greater than the limit set.

I've made an attempt at this, as seen in the code below. But unfortunately I receive an error message stating that there is an unexpected '>' which I know relates to the line I've added, but not sure how to code this another way.

**Revised Cut Down Code**

```
 <?php

   // This function makes usage of 
// $_GET, $_POST, etc... variables 
// completly safe in SQL queries 
function sql_safe($s) 
{ 
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) 
        $s = stripslashes($s); 

    return mysql_real_escape_string($s); 
} 

// If user pressed submit in one of the forms 
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') 
{ 
    if (!isset($_POST["action"])) 
    { 
        // cleaning title field 
        $title = trim(sql_safe($_POST['title'])); 

        if ($title == '') // if title is not set 
            $title = '(No title provided';// use (empty title) string 

        if (isset($_FILES['photo'])) 
        { 
            @list(, , $imtype, ) = getimagesize($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']); 
            // Get image type. 
            // We use @ to omit errors 

            if ($imtype == 3) // cheking image type 
                $ext="png";   // to use it later in HTTP headers 
            elseif ($imtype == 2) 
                $ext="jpeg"; 
            elseif ($imtype == 1) 
                $ext="gif"; 
            else 
                $msg = 'Error: unknown file format'; 

            if($_FILES["fileupload"]["size"]/1024000 >= 10) // 10mb 
            {     
            $fileErrMsg = "<br />Your uploaded file size:<strong>[ ". $_FILES["fileupload"]["size"]/1024000  . " MB]</strong> is more than allowed 10MB Size.<br />";        

            } 

            if (!isset($msg)) // If there was no error 
            { 
                $data = file_get_contents($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']); 
                $data = mysql_real_escape_string($data); 
                // Preparing data to be used in MySQL query 

                mysql_query("INSERT INTO {$table} 
                                SET ext='$ext', title='$title', 
                                    data='$data'"); 

                $msg = 'Success: Image Uploaded'; 
            } 
        }
```

I just wondered whether someone could perhaps take a look at this and let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Many thanks and kind regards

Comment: Which line is faulty? And don't use @ to suppress the error for debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this

```
if($_FILES["fileupload"]["size"]/1024000 >= 10) // 10mb
{
    $fileErrMsg = "<br />Your uploaded file size:<strong>[ ". $_FILES["fileupload"]["size"]/1024000  . " MB]</strong> is more than allowed 10MB Size.<br />";   
    }
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for looking at and replying to my post. I've tried the code you suggested, but, and this is very possibly down to my lack of experience. Even when the file size is over the limit, rather than receiving the appropriate message, I'm still receiving the 'unknown format' message. I've amended my original post to show the new. I just wondered whether you could perhaps take a look at this please and tell me where I'm going wrong. Once again many thanks and kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

[`getfilesize()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) returns image dimensions in pixels, not file size. You need something along the lines of this:

```
if (filesize($_FILES['tmp_name']) >= 100000)
```